# Thunderbird ate my sent folder

Tags: thunderbird

I have recently set up thunderbird on a new computer, linking it to an existing gmail account (pop).

I don't have a sent folder anymore and all my sent emails are placed in the inbox. How can I fix (meaning having a sent folder back that contains all my sent emails)?

## Edit:

kubuntu 18.04LTS. I had not sent an email yet at the time of writting this question.

Comment: To start with, 1) which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and 2) which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. 3) Have you sent messages from that PC since you configured Thunderbird for POP access to Gmail? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, problem solved (thanks to K7AAY's comment). Here is how:

a) send yourself an email. This will create the send folder.
b) Create a filter for the messages from:your email adress that moves these messages to your sent folder.

Voila